# Segmented control to switch views within view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I've been researching this for hours but can't find anything helpful. Anything I have tried just doesn't work.

I have a view controller with a collection view up top, along with a few other things in the bottom left half. Now in the bottom right corner I have a container view which holds a few text fields, buttons, textview, etc. The app I'm working on requires 4 different views within this cornered container. They'll carry most of the same things. I'm guessing that I need to make 4 other containers/views with whatever view elements are needed in them. I've found countless write ups on the hidden (YES/NO) property but I've also read it's not good for memory as it'll take up a lot of it.

If I can do this through storyboard that'd be great, but if I have to make the views in nib files that's cool too. Can anyone help me find a solution? Thank you in advance.

Comment: So what is it specifically that you don't know how to do? You can make your views in xib files, and load them when you need them. Remove the old view with removeFromSuperview, and add the new one. If you understand the basics of iOS programming, that's a simple thing to do.

Comment: i didn't know that removeFromSuperview existed. I've been doing this for 3 months now so there's a ton of things I don't know yet. Thanks for your help @rdelmar